# How to prevent cart wipe when BACK pressed?

Tags: asp.net, session

I have an ASP.NET application with a shopping-cart type of scenario.

I'm worried about the user clearing their cart by pressing BACK or REFRESH . What are some ways to prevent this?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //do stuff...

            //create a new list of items/ eg,  blank cart
            Session["shoppingcart"] = new List<InventoryItem>();
        }
    }
```

I want them to have an empty cart when they first arrive on the page. (In this scenario they never order more than 20 items so I'm not worried about overfilling the Session variable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want the shopping cart to be cleared out, then don't create a new shopping cart if one already exists.

Try:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ensure a shopping cart has been created
    if (Session["shoppingcart"] == null)
        Session["shoppingcart"] = new List<InventoryItem>();

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //do stuff...
    }
}
```